# Doctrine: Custom column alias with QueryBuilder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a function selecting all columns from a table, using QueryBuilder, and I would like to add a custom column to the resulting query. This is what I have:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->select(array('c', 'a'))
               ->from('models\Car', 'c')
               ->leftJoin('c.account', 'a')
               ->where('a.admin = 0');
```

Now, I would like to add a 'days car was in store' column, which in standard MySQL would be:

```
((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.daySold) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.dayArrived))/86400) as days_car_in_store
```

How can I achieve that by adding it to the constructed query above?

Comment: did this answer work?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
$sql = "((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.daySold) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.dayArrived))/86400)";

$qb->add('select', new Expr\Select(array('c', "{$sql} as days_car_in_store")))
```